# Create a dynamic new list by using other lists in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, nested-loops, ansible-2.x, ansible-filter

I've used `includ_vars` for importing a file which includes some variables as follows:

```
my_vars:
   - { name: "a", surname: "b", status: "c"}
   - { name: "d", surname: "e", status: "f"}
   - { name: "g", surname: "h", status: "i"}
```

I'm going to create a new dynamic list by `my_vars` and use it in `get_url` task:

```
- { url: "http://company.com/a/b/c.txt"}
- { url: "http://company.com/d/e/f.txt"}
- { url: "http://company.com/g/h/i.txt"}
```

---

```
- name: "include my_vars"
  include_vars:
    file: "../myvars.yml"

- name: "create new URL list"
  set_fact:
     new_list: "- {url: "http://"http://company.com/{{ my_vars.name }}/{{ my_vars.surname }}/{{ my_vars.status }}.txt
  with_items: {{ my_vars }}

- name: "get desired url"
  get_url:
      url: {{ item.url }}
      dest: /tmp/
  loop: {{ new_list }}
```

But it doesn't work. How can I create this new iterative list by existing variables for using in other steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the values

```yaml
my_vals: "{{ my_vars|json_query('[].[name, surname, status]')|
                     map('join', '/')|
                     list }}"
```

gives the list of the fragments

```yaml
my_vals:
  - a/b/c
  - d/e/f
  - g/h/i
```

Use the filter *product* to combine the fragments. Flatten and join the lists

```yaml
my_urls: "{{ ['http://company.com/']|product(my_vals)|
                                     product(['.txt'])|
                                     map('flatten')|
                                     map('join')|
                                     list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
my_urls:
  - http://company.com/a/b/c.txt
  - http://company.com/d/e/f.txt
  - http://company.com/g/h/i.txt
```

Use the filter *community.general.dict_kv* if you need the list of the dictionaries

```yaml
my_urls_dict: "{{ my_urls|map('community.general.dict_kv', 'url')|
                          list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
my_urls_dict:
  - {url: 'http://company.com/a/b/c.txt'}
  - {url: 'http://company.com/d/e/f.txt'}
  - {url: 'http://company.com/g/h/i.txt'}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    my_vars:
      - {name: "a", surname: "b", status: "c"}
      - {name: "d", surname: "e", status: "f"}
      - {name: "g", surname: "h", status: "i"}
    my_vals: "{{ my_vars|json_query('[].[name, surname, status]')|
                         map('join', '/')|
                         list }}"
    my_urls: "{{ ['http://company.com/']|product(my_vals)|
                                         product(['.txt'])|
                                         map('flatten')|
                                         map('join')|
                                         list }}"
    my_urls_dict: "{{ my_urls|map('community.general.dict_kv', 'url')|
                              list }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: my_urls
    - debug:
        var: my_urls_dict
```

---

Q: ***"How can I create a loop on objects with `status: 'f'` ?"***

A: Select the item. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ my_vars|selectattr('status', 'eq', 'f') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'd', 'surname': 'e', 'status': 'f'}) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item:
    name: d
    status: f
    surname: e
```

But this answer seems to be too obvious. You're probably asking how to select such an item when the *url* is created. There are many options:

- For example, combine the dictionaries

```yaml
my_urls_dict: "{{ my_urls|map('community.general.dict_kv', 'url')|
                          zip(my_vars)|
                          map('combine')|
                          list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
my_urls_dict:
  - {name: a, status: c, surname: b, url: 'http://company.com/a/b/c.txt'}
  - {name: d, status: f, surname: e, url: 'http://company.com/d/e/f.txt'}
  - {name: g, status: i, surname: h, url: 'http://company.com/g/h/i.txt'}
```

Then, the iteration is as trivial as before.

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ my_urls_dict|selectattr('status', 'eq', 'f') }}"
```

- The next option is the iteration of both lists together

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item
      with_together:
        - "{{ my_vars }}"
        - "{{ my_urls }}"
      when: item.0.status == 'f'
```

- The trivial option would be the concatenation of the *url* in the loop

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: url
      loop: "{{ my_vars|selectattr('status', 'eq', 'f') }}"
      vars:
        url: "http://company.com/{{ item.name }}/{{ item.surname }}/{{ item.status }}.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks, @vladimir-botka. How can I create a loop on objects with concrete 'status'.
i.e. create a loop on the objects that they have `status: "f"`

Comment: You are welcome, @Hamid. I added an example.

Comment: Perfect!, @vladimir-botka could you please recommend to me some useful resources (books, online courses, tutorials, ...) for learning to use these jinja filters in Ansible?

Comment: I haven't read any Ansible book for a while. IMHO any book and/or course can't cover all aspects. But, all resources are available online: [ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/), [jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/), [yaml](https://yaml.org/), [JmesPath](https://jmespath.org/specification.html), [python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/). If you ask me how have I learned it? The answer is: Read the doc and [practice](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-examples). Feel free to contiribute.

Comment: There are a couple of sources if you want to start with filters: [Ansible filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html), [Jinja filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters), and filters in the [Ansible collections](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/index.html), e.g. [community.general Filter Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide.html).

Comment: It's a moving target. See [Filter plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/filter.html#filter-plugins). See also how to develop [Filter plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins). It's [pretty straightforward](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins).

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need the variable `new_list`?

#### Possibly the better solution for your case

But if you only want to execute the download of the respective URLs, you can do it as follows:

```yaml
- name: "include my_vars"
  include_vars:
    file: "../myvars.yml"

- name: Get file from url
  get_url:
    url: "http://company.com/{{ item.name }}/{{ item.surname }}/{{ item.status }}.txt"
    dest: "/tmp/{{ item.name }}_{{ item.surname }}_{{ item.status }}.txt"
  with_items: "{{ my_vars }}"
```

If you want to continue working with the downloaded files later, you could do this in the same way as with the `get_url` task:

```yaml
- name: Remove downloaded files
  file:
    path: "/tmp/{{ item.name }}_{{ item.surname }}_{{ item.status }}.txt"
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{ my_vars }}"
```

Alternatively, you could download the files to an empty directory (e.g. `/tmp/my_downloaded_text_files/`), and then use the [`find` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html) to find all files in that directory.

#### Solution to dynamically create the list

I found a way to create the URL list, however I don't know if that is really the better option for your use case.

```yaml
- name: Create list with download URLs
  set_fact:
    new_list: "{{ ( new_list | default([]) ) + [ new_url_item ] }}"
  vars:
    new_url_item: "http://company.com/{{ item.name }}/{{ item.surname }}/{{ item.status }}.txt"
  with_items: "{{ my_vars }}"
```

You iterate over your list of dicts via `with_items`. As task variable you prepare the new entry (`new_url_item`). This new entry is then concatenated to the existing list in each iteration.

Comment: Thank you, @phanaz. Your solution works fine, but it is so slow (even with using Mitogen) It wants to download files in every execution regardless of existing files. I also checked `changed_when` but it doesn't work fine.